# wordpress database not showing in PhpMyAdmin

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am new to wordpress and have bought udesign theme from themeforest. from my Plesk I have installed WP and then from the dashboard of WP tried to upload the theme, but failed. hence went directly to dedicated server and hosted on the root folder.

Theme started reflecting on the dashboard and I have started customization. Once site completes I need to move the site to production server. When I check PhpMyAdmin from the plesk, it shows there is no DB table. how do I copy/move the site without DB?

Can i manage site without PhpMyAdmin? like copying the entire assets to new server and it starts working automatically?

Please help me to find DB or Let me know how to work with the themes to make sure everything in right place.

Many Thanks,
Gururaj

Comment: what did you give the db name during installation...? Remember one and find in phpmyadmin

Answer (score 0):

If you’ve ever had the need to find the name of your WordPress database, then there’s an easy way to do that – simply look for it in your wp-config.php file located in the root folder of your WordPress install.

**Accessing Your WP-Config.php File**

- If you are doing something where you need the name of your database, then I’m assuming you have access to your server.
- Simply go to the main folder of your WordPress install and locate the file called `wp-config.php`.
- Edit file and find name in:

  `define('db_name','your database here');`